# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate.CertificateAuthenticationHandler Certificate validation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm having some issues in production validating certificates.  I have the following setup.  A Kestrel web server implementation in ASP.NET Core using the following

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    string pass = @"my_complicated_password";
                    var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\certs\my_server_cert.pfx", pass);

                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                    {
                        o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(defaults =>
                        {
                            defaults.ServerCertificate = cert;
                            defaults.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                            defaults.AllowAnyClientCertificate();
                        });
                    });

                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.ListenAnyIP(8384, o =>
                        {
                            o.UseHttps();
                        });
                    });

                    webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

                });
    }
```

Now when I run locally I see the following

````
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'https://localhost:8384'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:8384
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\location_of_web_app
crit: MyNameSpace.CertificateValidationService[1]
      WE ARE IN THE VALIDATE CERT SECTION
crit: MyNameSpace.CertificateValidationService[2]
      THE CERT BEING PASSED WAS THE_PERSON```
````

This is what I'd expect.  However, on production, I see the following:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:8384
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\my_app_location
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate.CertificateAuthenticationHandler[2]
      Certificate validation failed, subject was [All the stuff 
      PartialChain A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
      RevocationStatusUnknown The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
      OfflineRevocation The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
```

I'm trying to determine what the missing step is, but this is a bit out of my expertise

Comment: Check the CA authority that has delivered the client certificate, and then ensure that this authority is trusted in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities of the server. Maybe you trust this CA on your local computer, or the CA's client certificate you use locally is trusted by your computer (or a self signed trusted). But if the server accepts any client certificate you must trust the CA of the client certificate. If the CA is not trusted locally on the server then the server should be able to connect to AIA endpoints include to ensure the certificate is valid.

Comment: @Hazrelle thank you - just to clarify.  You're saying to go to the production server (where this application resides)  and verify that the .pfx file and the whole chain shows up in the "Trust Root Certification Authorities"?

Basically, what I'm trying to do and maybe it's wrong is this.

Using the defaults.ServerCertificate = cert so the website shows the connection is secure.  Then the user authenticates with a different method (in this case via a X509 Cert that's on a CARD)  And that should hit the CertValidationService

Comment: Thank you - talking this through out loud made me realize I didn't have the chain for the CARD authorization.  GOD BLESS

Comment: The server side is probably fine. It's the client certificate chain that is not trusted by the production server :)

Comment: You were correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hazrelle posted, the issue was the client certificate chain was improperly configured on the production server.